# RTC capacitor with long lifetime selection

Tags: component-selection

In my design I am using for RTC ([BQ32000](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq32000.pdf)) circuit, for which I have used a 0.33F capacitor and it's rated lifetime is 2000 Hrs.

But I need to select a capacitor with 5000 Hrs lifetime.

I haven't found a part with 0.33F and a lifetime of 5000 Hrs.

My question is:

Can we place two capacitors in parallel to increase lifetime?

Alternatively where and how can I select a capacitor with a lifetime of 5000 Hrs.

Comment: can you install 32 bit os twice and make it 64 bit os??? the answer is NO

Comment: if you are talking about that backup part in the schematics ,use battery instead of capacitor or just use a super capacitor which is expected to last 130000 hours which is approx 15 years

Comment: @Lokanath I think it's not about how long the RTC will run, but how long the capacitor will actually hold - at least that is my speculation I built my answer around.

Comment: hold the charge for 5000 hours???

Comment: @Lokanath an on spec 0.33F capacitor will be able to run the RTC for approximately 97 hours. So I don't think the question is about running the RTC for 5000hrs straigth from a capacitor (you'd need 19F for that). But more a concern of the lifetime of the capacitor (when is it dead, so the circuit doesn't meet the specs)

Comment: yup i understood you right a super capacitor can last(lifetime) upto 15 years as per wiki so you can use that

Comment: @Lokanath that is at room temperature - it was not stated which kind of temperatures are expected, so I went for the worst and then you end up at 2000hrs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing to capacitors in parallel will have mainly two effects:

- lower effective series resistance
- increases capacity

It may increase the lifetime of the capacitor if the main stress (and cause of failure) is because of ripple currents. But generally it won't increase the lifetime as both parts are "living" in parallel, each using their lifespan. Twins don't have the double lifespan of a normal human either.

The lifetime of an electrolytic capacitor is often limited because of the electrolyte drying out. The higher the temperature the faster it will dry out.

I guess the capacitor you found was one rated for 2000hrs @ 85°C. I wasn't able to quickly find a supercap with a rated lifetime of more than that. So what are your options?

1. Review your requirements:

   How long is your RTC running without supply? -> do you really need 0.33F to bridge that time? Maybe you could use a smaller capacitor with longer lifetime? (10mF with 5000hrs @ 85°C is readily available)
2. Investigate other options:

   Maybe you can use a coin cell battery as backup? It stores a lot more energy than a capacitor, but you have to factor in self discharge and the temperature range might get further limited.
3. Can you place a temperature limit on your device?

   If the rated temperature of your product is 10K lower than the rated temperature of the capacitor, it's lifetime will roughly double. So if your device is usable only from -40°C to 75°C the lifetime of your capacitor will probably be 4000hrs. Note this is just a rough ballpark estimation and not a fact. Lifetime is a complex thing and if you have to be 100% sure you will have to do an in depth analysis using an approach with [Arrhenius equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation)
4. Is the end of life of the capacitor actually that bad for your intended use?

   Capacitors end of life is often specified by a loss of capacitance by 30% or an increase of the internal resistance by a factor of four. Now if you would use a bigger capacitor it would still have a capacitance of 0.33F after it's specified lifetime. So if you would use a 0.5F capacitor it would have 0.35F after 2000hrs and then it would last another 2000hrs to your end of life capacitance of 0.23F. The increase in internal resistance will make nearly no difference if you only draw a microampere from it.

A possibly related question, with good answers: [How durable is a supercapacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/how-durable-is-a-supercapacitor)

Comment: Thanks for your comments understanding better; i will investigate further product requirements

Comment: @Arumugam I just added another point to the list, might be worth investigating also.

Comment: really very helped me a lot to understand better